# Ansible - when condition does not work with custom variables

Tags: ansible

I try to apply a task in a playbook to only those hosts with a custom variable, but it does not work as expected. I would be happy if someone could help. The *host_var* includes the following variable:

```yaml
applications:
  - "ZFS_rhel_based"
```

and the when condition looks like:

```yaml
when: (ansible_os_family == "RedHat") and (kernel_upgrade is defined) and ("'*ZFS_rhel_based*' in applications")
```

Answer (score 2):

Given the inventory

```ini
shell> cat hosts
host_a
host_b
```

The below playbook

```yaml
shell> cat pb.yml 
- hosts: all

  vars:

    kernel_upgrade: is defined

  tasks:

    - debug:
        msg: |
          ansible_os_family: {{ ansible_os_family }}
          applications: {{ applications }}

    - debug:
        msg: We are happy!
      when: ansible_os_family == 'RedHat' and
            kernel_upgrade is defined and
            'ZFS_rhel_based' in applications
```

gives

```yaml
shell> ansible-playbook pb.yml

PLAY [all] ***********************************************************************************

TASK [debug] *********************************************************************************
ok: [host_a] => 
  msg: |-
    ansible_os_family: RedHat
    applications: ['ZFS_rhel_based']
ok: [host_b] => 
  msg: |-
    ansible_os_family: Debian
    applications: ['ZFS_rhel_based']

TASK [debug] *********************************************************************************
ok: [host_a] => 
  msg: We are happy!
skipping: [host_b]

PLAY RECAP ***********************************************************************************
host_a: ok=2    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0   
host_b: ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=1    rescued=0    ignored=0
```